# Image color modification via Javascript or PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, image, gd

I need to change the color of a transparent PNG that will not touch the 100% transparent part via Javascript or PHP. I would like to the the exactly same thing that Photoshop color overlay does on a layer (100% color overlay - no hue change).

I have already found a filter that can flip the image horizontally on StackOverflow (thanks guys!) but the solution to this I cannot find anywhere.

Please help and thanks in advance!

Comment: and what if you re-post the color changed image?

Answer (score 1):

Try [imagefilter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php) with `IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE`